# Why Git displays the contents of .gitignore file as untracked?

Tags: git, gitignore

Already read all the articles about the `.gitignore` file, but nothing helps. I will tell you honestly - I'm new to the study of the Git. The problem is that misrepresented the detailed design for your android, I added a line like this to ignore folder `bin/`. But after I call `git status` - that I have shown in the list of untracked folder `bin/`. I tried to add a `.gitignore` file to `my_project/` folder, or `my_project/.git/` folder - focused on the latest version. Deleted all the files from the list prepared. I again did wrong or what did not? 
/git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1/

Comment: What is the folder structure? Adding gitignore to your my_project/.git/ folder does not make any sense.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By2h7CMCiaOEY2VvWGFuVU11Zk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you save the file in the working directory and not in the local repository that everything works difference - but the list of untracked `.gitignore` appear, and so we have to write to `.gitignore` that you want to ignore `.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution, that line helped me:**

```
git config --local core.excludesfile .git/.gitignore
```

**Thanks ["GitHub Help"](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)**

EDIT: Or how prompts  @Charles Bailey  - register all paths and ignored files in `.git/info/exclude` file.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense, if you want a repository specific excludes file that isn't in the tracked repository contents then why not use the standard `.git/info/exclude`? There doesn't seem to be much point in creating a special file and having to add extra configuration to use it.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Thanks for the advice a good friend. Alas - but I'm new, did not know about such a possibility, no idea about the alternative path.

Comment: But it's documented in the help page that you linked to?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Really? I have not seen mention of the `.git/info/exclude` there.Or my English is much worse than I thought. English is not my native language, so I can not understand something.